# Magento Controller Dispatch doesn't render

Tags: controllers, 404-page

I followed this tutorial: blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller but it doesn't work for me. My files:

`/app/etc/modules/Baobaz_Arithmetic.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Baobaz_Arithmetic>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Baobaz_Arithmetic>
</modules>
</config>
```

`/app/code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/etc/config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Baobaz_Arithmetic>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Baobaz_Arithmetic>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <arithmetic>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Baobaz_Arithmetic</module>
                <frontName>arithmetic</frontName>
            </args>
        </arithmetic>
    </routers>   
</frontend>
</config>
```

`/app/code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/controllers/IntegerController.php`

```
<?php
 class Baobaz_Arithmetic_IntegerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
  public function multiplyAction(){
    echo "Respect my authoritah";
  }
 }
?>
```

I cleared the cache. When calling `(...).com/arithmetic/integer/multiply` I get `404 page`. I run `Magento 1.8.1`.

How to fix this?

Comment: put <?php at top of your controller

Comment: Just replicated your module on my side. It works perfectly. make sure you cleared the cache. If it's enabled you should disable it while developing. If you have the compiler enabled, disable it. Also make sure you have the `<?php` tag in your controller class as programmer_rkt said above.

Comment: Sorry, it was already in the file. I've just did't copy it. I've found an answer, will post it now.

Comment: call your controller like this `www.domain.com/index.php/arithmetic/integer/multiply`

Comment: @Marius : what !!! whether his url works ???? no way

Comment: @programmer_rkt. Yep. It worked on my side. Just like that.

Comment: @programmer_rkt: I tried usint index.php in url before, without /de/ but it didn't work as well. (...)/index.php/de/arithmetic(...) works. I am just thinking now if adding /de/ is a real soultion? Shouldn't it work without country code(and show default shop's language)?

Comment: @Alan : this is the first time I am seeing inclusion of a country code does the trick and other url that is supposed to work are not working. This is amazing !

Comment: @Marius : This is the first time I came to know about this. Can I know why this url worked ? If you know the answer, can you put it as an answer here. It's a humble request. I really want to know WHY it worked :)

Comment: it worked because it has the form it should have `module/controller/action`. Also it worked for me without the `de` part because I don't have the store codes in url setting enabled. Maybe it didn't work for you and you need to add `index.php` because you don't have the `mod_rewrite` module enabled on your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my website is in **German** and controller worked when I added `(...).com/de/ arithmetic/integer/multiply` (without spaces :).

Comment: Can I ask why you downwote?

Comment: can you try this url `www.domain.com/index.php/arithmetic/integer/multiply` ?

Comment: I'm curious why the downvotes also. The answer comes from the OP and states that it fixed the problem. You can vote to close as off topic but why downvote. Seams like a legit answer to me. Here is a +1 to compensate.

Comment: @Marius : i cant believe this url worked ! So downvoted ! when I realized it really worked, I became obliged and hence I removed downvoting and put an upvote. He teached me new thing. Thank you Alan  for this question. But still I am confused. How did that url worked ?????

Comment: Thanks Marius :). @programmer_rkt: I tried this. My reply is in comments below the question.

Comment: @Alan : +1 for you. You are the teacher of the day :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt: Thanks:). I jumped into this project in the middle of development so there already are some modules installed. I am not sure how they can affect my controller but if I get to know that I will surely let you know.

Comment: @Alan : i am waiting for your return